# Websocket handshake failing in Webkit with Socket.io 0.7

Tags: node.js, webkit, websocket, socket.io

I have upgraded my node.js app to work with the latest socket.io module. However, now only Firefox can connect, Chrome and Safari give this error: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'

Comment: Which versions of Chrome / Safari. Also try complaining in #socket.io

Comment: Google Chrome 12.0.742.112 / Safari 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem, using node 0.4.5 and socket.io 0.7.6 on dotcloud.

Comment: Temporary solution is to disable native websockets and use xhr-polling instead. I asked in #socket.io, nobody seems to know whats up, its not a common problem. I get the problem even with the hello world example app.

Comment: I have the same problem on Heroku, but they are using Nginx and state that they only support HTTP 1.0 (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing)

Answer (score 3):

Nginx is not compatible (out of the box) with HTTP 1.1, which is required for WebSockets. You will need to patch it (something I couldn't help you with, too much trouble) or you could use a node.js only stack.

I use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

See also: [Advantages of a reverse proxy in front of Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763571/advantages-of-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-node-js/6764661#6764661)

Comment: The development version of Nginx supports HTTP 1.1, so that's another option. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's totally nginx - I had everything working fine, changed some nonessential stuff and then it wouldn't work.  It's only after reading this that I realised that I'd stopped entering the port in the URL and thus was falling under nginx's proxying.  Added the port, worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Nginx version. v1.4 seems to work fine, whereas I had trouble with v1.2 (and had to upgrade).

Comment: FYI, if upgrading to 1.4 on Ubuntu, this is the resource you need: http://www.slashgeek.net/2013/05/08/how-to-get-the-latest-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-2-lts-precise-pangolin/